# facing issue while parsing xml containing xi:includes with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to parse xml's. I have a schema as below and also two xml files a.xml and b.xml defined on this schema. a.xml have a dependency over b.xml thru xi:include xml tag. Please file the below example for more clear data

```
 I have followng schema definition:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Task">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Details" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Details">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="NAme" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here are the two xml files:

a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Task xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
<Details>
    <xi:include href="b.xml"/>
</Details>
</Task>
```

b.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Detail>
  <Name>Name1</Name>
 </Detail>
<Detail>
   <Name>Name2</Name>
 </Detail>
```

Now I am parsing this using JAXB SAXFactory as:

```
 JAXBContext jaxbcon = JAXBContext.newInstance("schema-definition-jaxb-files");
 unmar = jaxbcon.createUnmarshaller();

 SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
 spf.setXIncludeAware(true);
 XMLReader xr = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
 SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource(new    FileInputStream(xmlfilename)));
 Object obj = unmar.unmarshal(source);
```

The parsing is successfull but the *Details* JAXB tag object is null. Anyhow the     xi:include tag in a.xml file is not flattened. any idea?

Comment: What does your domain model look like?

Comment: Blaise, sorry I didnt get you. waht is domain model?

Comment: Yes, I'm curious what you are trying to map to.

Comment: Hi Blaise thanks.... since the space provided here is less, I have create a new stackoverflow question with title "facing issue while parsing xml containing xi:includes with jaxb". Can you please look at this and help me how to resolve this issue. Thanks, Darshan

Comment: Schema typo? `<xs:element name="NAme"` -> `"Name"`? And in your schema you've defined `Details` as a sequence of `Name` elements, while you're really getting a sequence of `Detail` elements inside your `Details` element...

Comment: Torious thanks.. i created this small example explaining the scenario. Please concentrate on the problem since its the dummy scemas

Comment: Does JAXB work correctly, if you merge two XML files into one manually?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it definitely works:

```
public class Test {
    public String include;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setXIncludeAware(true);
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XMLReader xr = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        SAXSource src = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource("test.xml"));
        Test t = JAXB.unmarshal(src, Test.class);
        System.out.println(t.include);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have similar problem and I tried above approach, but still getting null for Details element. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

You shoud add

```
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
```